# How to generate a nmap HTML report with python?

Tags: python, xml, html, nmap

Given an `.xml` output file from a `nmap` scan, how would you suggest to generate an html report from this file?

`nmap` proposes the following utility with shell ([reference](https://nmap.org/book/output-formats-output-to-html.html#output-formats-fig-xml-browser)):

1. xsltproc

   ```
   xsltproc <nmap-output.xml> -o <nmap-output.html>
   ```
2. *Saxon*

   ```
   java -jar saxon9.jar -s:<nmap-output.xml> -o:<nmap-output.html>
   ```
3. *Xalan*

   ```
   Xalan -a <nmap-output.xml> -o <nmap-output.html>
   ```

**Which python code can I use instead of one of those commands?**

PS: I am looking for a solution valid on Unices and Windows (running bash from pyhon is not a solution)